# Wrap all post images inside a div element

Tags: images, hooks

I searched for all kind of solution but i really could find one that did what i was looking for, what i simple want done is wrapping all images inside a div element, old post aswell as new posts. All help is very much appreciated

p.s.
I did a little jquery snippet but I really would like another solution

the jquery code

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('a:has(img.postthumbimage)').wrap('<div class="myphoto" />');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post the code that outputs your images?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using PHP's regular expression find/replace function—`preg_replace()`—in a filter on the `the_content` hook.

```
function breezer_addDivToImage( $content ) {

   // A regular expression of what to look for.
   $pattern = '/(<img([^>]*)>)/i';
   // What to replace it with. $1 refers to the content in the first 'capture group', in parentheses above
   $replacement = '<div class="myphoto">$1</div>';

   // run preg_replace() on the $content
   $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );

   // return the processed content
   return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'breezer_addDivToImage' );
```

Note that this will only affect images inside post content.

If you want to wrap images that occur outside of the post body (such as featured images or images in custom fields), the most efficient way is probably to find where they occur and add the div wrapper to your theme file.

Comment: This solution doesn't work when you have a caption in your image